# MySQL extract data from text using RegEx

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table in MySQL, and I need to extract some data from a column using a regular expression.

The column (varchar, utf8_unicode_ci) has entries like this:

```
Some Text with spaces 6.112% 10-NOV-2021
```

I would like to extract the percentage number.

```
6.112%
```

And / or FROM the percentage number

```
6.112% 10-NOV-2021
```

Not all numbers have the same number of digits.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is the percentage always before the date? Is the date fixed length (eg. 01-NOV-2021 as opposed to 1-NOV-2021)?

Comment: Bill's right, there is no way to accomplish this in MySQL (though there is in MariaDB). You'll need to look for the last space before the `%` and use substr.